# Error during PayPal Express Checkout Integration in Sandbox

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using `React` for implementing `PayPal` Express Checkout. I have implemented it using [react-paypal-express-checkout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-express-checkout)

Now the app is in `Sandbox` mode. Here I could place the button and it will open the login popup while clicking on the button.
After logged in I couldn't  verify the transaction from the PayPal. It only shows a `"Return to Merchant"` button in the window as shown below (window titled as `please try again`).

[image]

Don't know what is the problem. But when I am giving a different Client ID from PayPal's sample code, it works perfectly.

Don't know why my Client ID is not working ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: When you created your REST API credentials, did you specify credentials for the sandbox? You should have separate ClientIDs for live vs. sandbox.

Also, are you able to login to your sandbox seller account and see the transaction results from either your ClientID or the PayPal sample ClientID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was with my app Client ID. Don't know why

I have generated a new app and client ID for this. Now it is working perfectly.